# How to store datatable on clientside variables

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have huge amount of data from database, i need to get or store that data temporarily in a variable on client side and display in another page. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How much data are we talking about here? And if you could elaborate a little bit more on how you need this data to be displayed on the client side it would be helpful. If you're developing in ASP.NET for the web there are quite a few controls such as repeater that you can use to display this kind of information.

Comment: I am capturing a screen with controls and saving that in a html file and providing a link to display. If i Click that link, i need to show that.

Comment: What database are you using? And what kind of application is this, ASP.NET?

Comment: I dont know how  big the data is but its probably not a good idea to store huge data on the client side for page performance, its better to get the data when its actually needed, maybe using AJAX calls.

Comment: How do this screen, capturing and html relate to the data, database and pages in question?

Comment: Jesse: Database using Sql server, it's Machine/Men usable product.

Comment: @Zespri: i am capturing in a HTML format and saving it to database.

Comment: So to clarify you only need to display information from the database when the user clicks a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic work flow to accomplish this would be as follows:

- Create an entity model in your solution to link to the database
- When the user clicks the button in your webpage use a method in your aspx.cs to go into the entity model and retrieve the item from your table using a primary key or some other identifier
- Pass the information back up to the web layer and display it inside of an update panel to prevent needing to to a full page reload
- You can also use jQuery's AJAX library to accomplish this.

Are you at all familiar with the Entity Framework for connecting to databases? This would be a good place to start. It's hard to help answer your question if you don't understand any of these concepts without going into a fair bit of detail and teaching to get you up to speed so you might need to do some reading/research on your own.

Comment: I'm feeling somewhat generous tonight so if you have specific questions about these steps I will try to help you flush it out but I definitely suggest you do some research on entity framework.